# Best way to start a new node.js mp3 stream and quit previous one, playfile(pathToNextMp3){}

Tags: node.js

What is the correct way of repeatedly stopping a stream and starting a new one from a playfile(pathToNextMp3){} function

Hi I am using this example of how to stream from a mp3 file

https://gist.github.com/TooTallNate/3947591

Any tips on creating a  function something like the below

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var lame = require('lame');
    var audioOptions = {channels: 2, bitDepth: 16, sampleRate: 44100};
    var Speaker = require('speaker');

/**
* @usage  I hoping to immediately kill previously launched stream 
* and safely start a new one on each call
*
*/
function playfile(pathToNextMp3) {
    // hope to first safely close previously launched stream here
    // maybe involving  lastInputStream, lastSpeaker, lastDecoder

    var speaker = new Speaker(audioOptions);
    var decoder = lame.Decoder();
    var inputStream = fs.createReadStream(pathToNextMp3);
    inputStream.pipe(decoder).pipe(speaker);
}
```